# Join Multiple Tables in LINQ and group the result

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to perform a Join of multiple tables in LINQ.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Project {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Batch {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Decimal Hours { get; set; }
    public Decimal DailyRate { get; set; }
}

public class TimeEntry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BatchId { get; set; }
    public Decimal Expense { get; set; }
}
```

I am joining these Tables with the following LINQ expression, which worked like a charm:

```
from project in _context.Projects
join batch in _context.Batches on project.Id equals batch.ProjectId into batchGroup from batch in batchGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join timeEntry in _context.TimeEntries on batch.Id equals timeEntry.BatchId into timeEntryGroup from timeEntriy in timeEntryGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
    project,
    batch,
    timeEntriy
};
```

But when I try to group the result i get an exception

```
from project in _context.Projects
join batch in _context.Batches on project.Id equals batch.ProjectId into batchGroup from batch in batchGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join timeEntry in _context.TimeEntries on batch.Id equals timeEntry.BatchId into timeEntryGroup from timeEntriy in timeEntryGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
group  new {
    project,
    batch,
    timeEntriy
} by project.Id into g
select new {
    Id = g.Key,
    Hours = g.Sum(q => (q.batch == null ? 0 : q.batch.Hours))
};

// "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Can someone explain me what happens here or what i am missing?

Comment: You are facing *default* part of `DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: Are you using EF?

Comment: I'm using EF Core

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I am using DefaultIfEmpty, because i want to achive an Left Joint [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause).
But I doesn't understand why the join is working, but the join and group is not working.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I think I've seen this exception. It's not a typical NRE because it's caused by EF Core implementation bugs and not the user code. It's sad that MS released such bugs and we need basically to redirect OPs to their issue tracker. But I don't think we should treat them as regular NRE duplicates.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I don't think this is a duplicate.